# ValueError: could not convert string to float: '5.9,3,4.2,1.5'

Tags: python, python-3.x, valueerror

I am using the following code to extract the first 4 objects in a text file to use for clustering, after the first 4 objects the rest of the line is a string. I keep getting this error and can't seem to find a workaround. the line that is committed out was from my textbook. I am trying to use index to pull the first 4 objects of the line.

```py
file = ('iris.txt')

x = []

with open(file, 'r') as f:

    for line in f.readlines():
        data = [float(i) for i in line.split(',')] #line not working 
        data = [float(i[0:13]) for i in line.split()]
        x.append(data)
    data = np.array(x)




size = []

rangeValues = np.arange(2, 10)

    for i in rangeValues:
        kmeans = KMeans(init='k-means++', n_clusters=i, n_init=10)
        kmeans.fit(data)
        size = metrics.silhouette_score(data, kmeans.labels_, metric='euclidean', sample_size=len(data))
        print("Number of Clusters =", i)
        print("Silhoutte Score =", size)
        size.append(size)
```

Comment: it seems more likely that the failing line is `data = [float(i[0:13]) for i in line.split()]`

Comment: Use the following. `import pandas as pd`, `import seaborn as sns`, `iris = sns.load_dataset('iris')` and `display(iris)`.  If you want to load your `iris.txt`, then use `iris = pd.read_csv('iris.txt')`.

Comment: You don't think it is a coincidence that the error refers to a line with exactly 13 characters? Get fid of the second assignment to `data`; even if it didn't raise an error, it would be overwriting the list assigned on the previous line, so one of the two lines is unnecessary.

Comment: the second line to data I have committed out in my program, I just referenced it to explain that I tried changing it to run but I can't get it to pull out the numbers from the text.

Comment: with open(file, 'r') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        data = line.strip(',')
        print(data)
        data = [float(i[0:13]) for i in line.strip(',')]
        x.append(data)
    data = np.array(x)